Using Shell Script to Tag Files
My MacBook is running OS Sequoia 15.1. How can I apply file color tags (labels) using zsh shell script? And how can I then use a shell script to change labels say if I want to change a label from green to red?
I have tried many variations using osascript commands but nothing seems to work. Every attempt returns an error stating that finder can't set label index. Is there a way to color tag MacOS files other than using osascript?
Here is an example of what happens using terminal:
% touch "/Users/xxxxxx/test_file.txt" osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to set label index of POSIX file "/Users/xxxxxx/test_file.txt" to 2'

29:118: execution error: Finder got an error: Can’t set label index of file "Macintosh HD:Users:xxxxxx:test_file.txt" to 2. (-10006) %

I get the same thing using osascript command in a bash script. I also cannot get Hazel or Keyboard Maestro to set file tags.
